# Is there a spell that protects you from ability damage

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells

Is there a spell that protects you from ability damage? I am not looking for spells that restore ability points. E.g. the text of borrowed time says:

> If you're immune to ability damage, you take 5 points of hit point damage instead.

So, is this example I want to have a spell on me to get the 5 points of hit point damage.

Comment: Is the immunity to ability damage specifically to better employ the spell *borrowed time* or is that--really and solely--just an example?

Comment: It is just an example

Comment: Then is there an effect that you need immunity to ability damage *for*? Or are you trying to be immune to ability damage because it's just so darn useful? (I'm not trying to, like, interrogate you or anything; it's just this sounds like it could be an [X/Y Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).)

Comment: We run into the problem of ability drain all day long. Our cleric can restore them with no problem (but often on another day or after the fight.) So I was looking for a way to get immune to the drain. This would help my wizard to be prepared for the ability damage of borrowed time as well but this should be just a subset of the solution I am looking for.

Comment: You could look for a spell or effect that changes your type or subtype to one immune to ability damage/drain.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Spell choices to do what you want are limited, so I'm including Wondrous Items in my answer. I hope you don't mind. Prices are purchase, not craft.

### For Poison type Damage

You could consider [Ointment, Restorative](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/wondrous-items/wondrous-items/m-p/ointment-restorative); 4000g for 5 uses. The spell it uses is [Neutralize Poison](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/n/neutralize-poison) (Cleric 4) which can prevent worsening Damage but not heal it.

Greater Neutralize Poison(Cleric 6) counters Damage from poison and is a Standard Action.

[Periapt of Proof against Poison](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/wondrous-items/wondrous-items/m-p/periapt-of-proof-against-poison) sets you back a hefty 27,000 ea but is a permanent solution.

### For Negative Energy (undead etc)

Your GM may or may not allow [Death Ward](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/d/death-ward) (Cleric, etc 4th-5th level) to prevent it. It works on negative levels but it's [unclear](http://www.giantitp.com/forums/showthread.php?121472-Death-Ward) whether ability Damage from undead creatures falls under Death Ward's protection against "any negative energy effects". I think most GM's allow it to work, but I'd ask instead of assuming.

### More Generally

[Contingency](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/c/contingency) (Wizard/Sorc 6) with Restoration or similar 'when an Ability falls below X' or just when 'x Ability Damages accrue'.

It's not magic but Barbarians can take [Renewed Vitality](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/barbarian/rage-powers/paizo---rage-powers/renewed-vitality-ex) to help themself.

[Ring of Inner Fortitude](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/rings/ring-of-inner-fortitude) (16,000/42,000/66,000 ea) can mitigate all forms of Damage (and as a bonus Drain) by 2(1), 4(2), or 6(3) until you have time to heal up. If you take 2 Dex and 2 Con Damage, you would effectively not lose anything, the 2(4, 6) applies to each Ability separately.

[Stalwart Resolve](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/s/stalwart-resolve) (Cleric 2) allows you to ignore all Damage to 1 Ability for 1rd/level of the Cleric. It might get you through a fight, at least. Bonus, you could buy/make scrolls or wands of it. Takes a Standard Action to counter one type of Damage, though.

Alternately, refocus on preventing the Damage. Buffing the party's Dexterity and Constitution will help you get hit less and succeed Fort saves more, preventing ability Damage/Drain.

Answer (score 1):

[Polymorph any object](http://www.archivesofnethys.com/SpellDisplay.aspx?ItemName=Polymorph%20Any%20Object) to turn you into a [Kolyarut Inevitable](http://www.archivesofnethys.com/MonsterDisplay.aspx?ItemName=Kolyarut).
Inevitables are immune to ability drain and -damage, they are medium size which increases the duration if your original pc is medium size, too.

The drawback is that you are not yourself anymore.

Comment: This isnt 3.5 so your subtype does not change and none of the spells listed grant you the immunity to ability drain, so even if you did take that form, you wouldnt benefit from it